# Is it OK to edit multiple tag wikis, adding excerpts only?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I have been editing a lot of tag wikis lately. I have focused on writing short definitions for tags without a wiki. This is in general tags with few questions. Since this is a rather quick thing to do, I have been doing a lot of them.

My rational for doing this is that I think having at least a short definition on the tags help prevent confusion and the kind of tag mess often seen at Stack Overflow, where the same tag has multiple meaning.

Is this an OK thing to do, or am I just spamming a review queue somewhere and annoying people? Those of you who have reviewed my edits, do you have any other feedback or tips?